# Long exact sequence of homotopy groups groups in simplicial sets - reference request

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, model-categories

I believe it is well-known that for a based map $f:X\to Y$ of simplicial sets (possibly with some extra hypotheses on $X$ and $Y$), there is a long exact sequence
$$
\ldots \to \pi_n(F)\to \pi_n(X) \to \pi_n(Y) \to \pi_{n-1}(F) \to \ldots,
$$
where $F$ is the homotopy fibre of $f$. However, I cannot actually find a precise statement of this result. The closest I've come is [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/long+exact+sequence+of+homotopy+groups) nLab page, which states essentially the same result for $\infty$-groupoids. I know that the classical model structure on simplicial sets is a presentation for
the $(\infty,1)$-category of $\infty$-groupoids, so I suspect that maybe the result holds specifically for fibrant-cofibrant simplicial sets, but I'm not sure.

Ideally, I would like a reference that states the result explicitly for simplicial sets. If no such reference exists, I'd also be grateful for an explanation of the result.

Comment: See Lemma I.7.3 in Goerss-Jardine.

Comment: @JHF that lemma refers to a strict fibre, rather than a homotopy fibre though. Is there some reason why it amounts to the same thing?

Comment: To compute the homotopy fibre, take a fibrant replacement of your map and compute the strict fibre.  The replacement is weak homotopy equivalent, so its homotopy groups are (functorially) isomorphic.

Comment: @JHF, thank you, I see now!